# Get an Objectify Entity's Key

Tags: google-app-engine, key, objectify

Dummy question.

I create my POJO Objectify entity (for example, "Category") and persist it.

Then I retrieve it via a query.

I want to use it in a one-to-may relationship e.g. want to set my category to one or more "Products".

I will have this in my "Product"'s code: `Key<Categoria> categoria;`

So the question is: how can I find my retrieved entity's key for setting it in my product?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm usually adding an extra method:

```
@Transient
Key<Categoria> getKey() {
   return Key.create(Categoria.class, id);
}
```

and use it where it needed:

```
anCategoria.getKey()
```

Comment: In Objectify 4 it gives me an error: that constructor is not visible.

Comment: `Key.create(Categoria.class, id)` - slightly more convenient than the constructor.

Answer (score 13):

For objectify 4 use:

```
public Key<Foo> getKey() {
   return Key.create(Foo.class, id);
}
```

Or if the entity has a @Parent

```
public Key<Bar> getKey() {
   return Key.create(parentKey, Bar.class, id);
}
```

Comment: Users should note that if a @Parent is defined the parent key MUST be used to generate the Bar key.

Comment: Is there a way to get the Key without writing new code for each Entity?

Answer (score 1):

The Key class in Objectify 4 has this method:

```
public static <T> Key<T> create(T pojo)
```

so, if you already have read the entity (called `category` in this example) from the datastore, you can just call

```
product.categoria = Key.create(category);
```