# Getting an Entity key

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

Based on the Q&A from here:
[Get an Objectify Entity's Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162141/get-an-objectify-entitys-key)

For a persisted object, getting the entity key with:

```
@Transient
Key<Categoria> getKey() {
   return new Key<Categoria>(Categoria.class, id);
}
```

Doensn't return the same key with:

```
Objectify ofy = ObjectifyService.begin();
Key<Categoria> key = ofy.getFactory().getKey(someobject);
```

Or should it?

My model looks like this:

```
@Entity
class Categoria{
  @Parent
  private Key<Someclass> parentKey;

  @Transient
  Key<Categoria> getKey() {
   return new Key<Categoria>(Categoria.class, id);
 }
 // Code omitted
}
```

Comment: maybe they're not the same (`==`) keys, but the should be equal (`.equals()`). Aren't they?

Comment: I am actually comparing the keys by their string representation, like testobjectKey.getString()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will only produce a different key if `Categoria` has a `@Parent` field.  In that case, you need to pass the parent key into the Key constructor along with the class and id.

Comment: I see. However i have another key for the one with @Parent. The getKey method returns a key that does not have that annotation

Comment: Why my app generate key that does not have that annotation?

Comment: I'm sorry but I really don't understand what you are asking.  Can you rephrase the question?

Comment: you need to `return new Key<Categoria>(parentKey, Categoria.class, id);`

Comment: @ori I did add the parent key in the parameter however the key returned by the "getKey" function still is different from what is returned by the factory

Comment: Then perhaps you are not constructing the parent key properly (eg, it has parents)?  Really, this code is in widespread use - it's almost impossible for something this simple to be broken.  Try posting a complete test case.

Answer (score 0):

It should.  I always get Objectify Entities via keys created from the a long id.  You can also use the returned key  to get the long id from the key if needed.

EDIT:
You can't get the key the way you are trying.

You have to do.

```
Key<Car> rootKey = new Key<Car>(Car.class, 959);
Key<Car> keyWithParent = new Key<Car>(parent, Car.class, 959);
```

[from the objectify wiki](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Concepts#Keys)

So for this line:
    Key key = ofy.getFactory().getKey(someobject);

key will consist of both the parent key PLUS the Categoria key

that means you have to include the parent key when you do the lookup in your function

```
Key<Categoria> getKey() {
 return new Key<Categoria>(parentKey, Categoria.class, id);
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by "You can't get the key the way you are trying."; I mean, are you saying that the getKey function from your answer should return the same key with the one I get from the factory method?

Comment: The issue I am facing is that, I need to get some entity from the datastore using the key, however the key provided by the "getKey" function here won't allow me to get the entity whereas when I use the key generated or provided by the factory, I can get the entity from the datastore.

Comment: as mentioned, you have to use the parent key in the "getKey" function to return the entity.